# Gwibber and the Messaging Menu

Tags: 10.10, gwibber

I would like to make Gwibber use the Messaging Menu in Ubuntu 10.10. Gwibber is running, there is an arrow near 'Broadcast' item, but i don't see recent tweets on the list, I just see Notify OSD notifications...

what can I do to make it work? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working.  It only shows notifications for @-replies.

Comment: well, I checked, it's true! Messaging menu only shows @-replies. Tnx!